# HTTP GET does not work fine on angular-electron project BUT same url works fine on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http, electron

i am trying to use https://api.pcloud.com/getfilelink API for my graduation project. But i think i have problem with api's CORS or something like that.

When i send get from chrome browser or basic node js project api returns fine json but if i try it from my angular-electron project(https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) it is returning 'invalid link referer'.

What i have tried:

- Appending ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); ('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest') to headers. But i have gotten "Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response." like returns.
- Adding proxy.conf.json to my project. Then i added "--proxy-config proxy.conf.json" to package.json but project gave "ERROR: Invalid Option: --proxy-config" while starting. Then i added "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json" to angular.json it started normally. But it didn't fix the problem.

My Code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
    getFileLink
}

let url = new URL('https://api.pcloud.com/getfilelink');
url.searchParams.append('access_token', 'glD5...d8F7');
url.searchParams.append('fileid', '21...92');

const headers = new Headers;
// headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
// headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

console.log(url.toString());

async function getFileLink() {

    let response = await fetch(url, {headers: headers});

    responseJSON = await response.json();

    return responseJSON;

}
```

This is working on basic node project but not working on angular-electron.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you calling the api? main or renderer?

Comment: This js module is in the same directory with service.ts which i am calling it. So i am calling it from renderer. Because i should. There is a button in my component.ts, it is calling service.ts and service.ts is calling module.js then module.js is calling api.

Comment: then make sure if you enabled nodeintegration when you are creating browserWindow

Comment: I checked nodeintegration was already true.

Comment: Can someone help me?