# Can i use http-proxy for each request that i do from node module in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

Or should i? I really don't know. I have a problem with angular's (i think angular) proxy settings. I asked a question about this few days ago but i didnt get answer:

[HTTP GET does not work fine on angular-electron project BUT same url works fine on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643455/http-get-does-not-work-fine-on-angular-electron-project-but-same-url-works-fine)

Here is my download.js module that is in electron-angular project hierarchy:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
    getFileLink
}

let url = new URL('https://api.pcloud.com/getfilelink');
url.searchParams.append('access_token', 'glD5...d8F7');
url.searchParams.append('fileid', '21...92');

console.log(url.toString());

async function getFileLink() {

    let response = await fetch(url, {headers: headers});

    responseJSON = await response.json();

    return responseJSON;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of each request.you have to set the proxy globally or in system to call the API

Comment: If i build the project will proxy settings be builted in project? If yes, how can i set proxy settings? proxy.conf.json? I tried it, it didnt work.